# Eclipse showing error for multiple declaration that is only declared once

Tags: c, eclipse-cdt

I have a c project in eclipse that is showing "symbol could not be resolved errors".  The symbol is a typedef enum.

When I right click on the symbol and go to open declaration it shows two header files, gpioh. and sensor.h.

It is declared in gpio.h

```
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file           : gpio.h
  * @brief          : Header for gpio.c file.
  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * <h2><center>&copy; Copyright (c) 2019 Hennessy Industries</center></h2>
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */


/* Define to prevent recursive inclusion -------------------------------------*/
#ifndef __GPIO_H
#define __GPIO_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#include "FreeRTOS.h"
#include "diag/Trace.h"
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "event_groups.h"

#define GPIO_SWITCH_ONE_DOWN    GPIO_PIN_4
#define GPIO_SWITCH_ONE_UP      GPIO_PIN_10
#define GPIO_SWITCH_TWO_DOWN    GPIO_PIN_7
#define GPIO_SWITCH_TWO_UP      GPIO_PIN_6
#define GPIO_SWITCH_THREE_DOWN  GPIO_PIN_8
#define GPIO_SWITCH_THREE_UP    GPIO_PIN_9

/* Constants */
typedef enum {
    SWITCH_ONE_DOWN = 0,
    SWITCH_ONE_UP,
    SWITCH_TWO_DOWN,
    SWITCH_TWO_UP,
    SWITCH_THREE_DOWN,
    SWITCH_THREE_UP}
SWITCH_IDS;

/* Functions */
void InitGIO(void);
void SwitchDebounceTask(void *arg);

/* Variables */
TaskHandle_t switchTaskHandle;

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif /* __GPIO_H */
```

It isn't declared in sensor.h (it used to be but I moved it)

```
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file           : sensor.h
  * @brief          : Header for sensor.c file.
  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * <h2><center>&copy; Copyright (c) 2019 Hennessy Industries</center></h2>
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */


/* Define to prevent recursive inclusion -------------------------------------*/
#ifndef __SENSOR_H
#define __SENSOR_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#include "FreeRTOS.h"
#include "diag/Trace.h"
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "event_groups.h"

/* Constants */

/* Functions */

void InitSensor(void);

/* Variables */


#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif /* __SENSOR_H_H */
```

I have refreshed the files and restarted eclipse but it is still showing the error.  The project builds ok, but it shows up as errors in the problem list.

Comment: Maybe do a clean build?

Comment: "The symbol is a typedef enum." and is it actually `SWITCH_IDS`?

Comment: Clean build hasn't helped.. yes, it is SWITCH_IDS